# AWK CSV stream editing, merge third columns for identical first columns when second column >= 0

Tags: streaming, editing, csv, awk, string

I'm on Windows and have only heard of linuxes awk etc so I can only imagine that this is possible without actual scripting:

I have data like

```
..
162     42      A single serving
162     62      of french fries, please
164     -1      ABC
164     -1      1
..
```

that I would like to be turned into

```
..
A single serving of french fries, please
..
```

so the rule would be

merge third columns for identical first columns when second column >= 0.

I'll try to find awk for Windows.

Comment: Here's [GNU awk for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) (download dependencies as well).

Comment: `gawk "$2 >= 0 { print $3 }" txt.txt` gives me the strings I want, but not yet grouped by the first column..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arrays to build up the strings:

```
awk -F '\t' '
  $2 >= 0 {str[$1] = str[$1] $3 " "}
  END {for (s in str) print str[s]}
' filename
```

I hope your data is actually tab-separated because otherwise $3 == "A" for the first line.

Comment: Fantastic. This works on Windows `gawk -F "\t" "$2 >= 0 {str[$1] = str[$1] $3 \" \"} END {for (s in str) print str[s]} " %1`